# Javascript error "el.addClass i s not a function" when trying to render fullcalendar as a custom html element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fullcalendar, velo

I am currently helping a friend with their Wix website to install [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io). The NPM package has been installed through the Corvid package manager.

I then created a custom element in Corvid, with the code below in the JavaScript file for that custom element, which has a tag of wix-calendar.
EDIT - As suggested, I have updated the code which is now showing an error along with console logs.

Please see Part 1 (the code) and Part 2 (the output) below.

Part 1:  js that is linked to the wix custom html component:

```
import { React } from "react";
import { Calendar } from "fullcalendar";
import { jquery } from "jquery";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
const DEBUG_TEXT = '1-class definitions callback';
const DEBUG_TEXT2 = '2-render function called';
const calendarContainer = document.createElement('div');
console.log("here we go");

class WixFullCalendar extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(DEBUG_TEXT);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
  const calendarEl = document.createElement('div');
  calendarEl.setAttribute('id', 'calendar');
  console.log(calendarEl);

  const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]

  });



  console.log(DEBUG_TEXT2)
  calendar.render();

  }
}
customElements.define('wix-calendar', WixFullCalendar);
```

Part 2: console output

```
   here we go wix-calendar.js:14 
    1-class definitions callback wix-calendar.js:20 
    <div id=​"calendar">​</div>​ wix-calendar.js:29 
    2-render function called fullcalendar.js:10807
      <div id="calendar"></div>
   > Uncaught TypeError: el.addClass is not a function
    >     at Calendar.initialRender (fullcalendar.js:10807)
    >     at Calendar.render (fullcalendar.js:10796)
    >     at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (wix-calendar.js:30)
    >     at Object.12.@fullcalendar/daygrid (wix-calendar.js:34)
    >     at o (_prelude.js:1)
    >     at r (_prelude.js:1)
    >     at _prelude.js:1
    >     at _prelude.js:1
    >     at _prelude.js:1 Calendar.initialRender @ fullcalendar.js:10800 Calendar.render @ fullcalendar.js:10794 connectedCallback @
    > wix-calendar.js:30
    > 12.@fullcalendar/daygrid @ wix-calendar.js:34 o @ _prelude.js:1 r @ _prelude.js:1 (anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1 (anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1 (anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1
```

Comment: One basic check: are you certain that `this.appendChild(createCalendarContainer())` is being executed _before_ `var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');`? Because it won't work otherwise, as the calendar element won't exist yet. Maybe you should consider having all the code which draws the calendar inside the `createCalendarContainer` callback? I don't know precisely how this Wix stuff is supposed to work, but that's an idea, if there are timing issues of the sort I've just described. Without any error messages or other debugging info, that's my best guess as to the problem.

Comment: @ADyson  Hi thank you for your response. I am definitely still learning when it comes to es6, I come from a front end background but more along the lines of traditional js and jquery.    The challenging part here is that Wix won't allow me to put <div id="calendar"></div> into the body, so I feel your comment about fixing the timing may be spot-on. Can you please provide an example of how I can rearrange my code to ensure everything executes in the correct order?

Comment: Well it would be helpful if you could first confirm whether the timing idea is correct? Adding some simple console logging to the code should enable you to see the order in which the different bits of code are executing.

Comment: @ADyson could you please review the updated code and console message and let me know any suggestions?

Comment: Something odd is going on here. `addClass` is a jQuery function. fullCalendar v4 doesn't use jQuery anymore, but v3 did. Have you somehow managed to include some fullCalendar v3 files in your build?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting the div thru Wix Dashboard/Tracking Tools & Analytics?

Comment: Hi @giri I did try as you suggested, adding <div id="calendar"></div> using the Tracking & Analytics section, adding it just after the opening <body> tag, however when previewing the site, the div did not appear.